# How To Know When A Group Of BackgroundWorkers Are Done

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a list of URLs and for each URL a BackgroundWorker is created to handle downloading data and updating its respective ProgressBar.

My question is how can I determine when all of the downloads have completed? As of right now, I only can find out when each BackgroundWorker finishes individually but not as a group.

```
for (int i = 0; i < videos.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    string path = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.DownloadLocation,
        videos[index].Title + videos[index].AudioExtension);
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker
    {
        WorkerReportsProgress = true,
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = false
    };
    worker.DoWork += delegate
    {
        AudioDownloader audioDownloader = new AudioDownloader(videos[index], path);
        audioDownloader.AudioExtractionProgressChanged += (obj, args) =>
        {
            int progress = (int)Math.Round(85 + args.ProgressPercentage * 0.15);
            worker.ReportProgress(progress);
        };
        audioDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (obj, args) =>
        {
            int progress = (int)Math.Round(args.ProgressPercentage * 0.85);
            worker.ReportProgress(progress);
        };
        audioDownloader.Execute();
    };
    worker.ProgressChanged += (obj, args) =>
    {
        progressi[index].Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
    {
        Notify(videos[index].Title + " is finished downloading.");
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I was considering doing something like this:

```
Task[] downloadTasks = new Task[videos.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < videos.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    downloadTasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Create BackgroundWorker and run it
        });
}
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(downloadTasks, (tasks) =>
{
    // All the downloads are complete!
});
```

But the ContinueWhenAll runs before the downloads are actually complete, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are doing this

```
for (int i = 0; i < videos.Count; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    downloadTasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Create BackgroundWorker and run it
        });
}
```

you create some background worker and tell them to do something in another thread. so just after telling them to do their work your tasks' job is finished so all of them (tasks) will be finished in a moment and

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(downloadTasks, (tasks) =>
   {
       // All the downloads are complete!
   });
```

checks if all tasks have done their work? the answer is: Yes! they all created a background worker and tell them what to do.

you can use some kind of flags, assign each background worker an Id and set a boolean in an array when it has finished it's work. check if all of them has finished their work and then go on. you can do this in your `Notify` method. check if all of the flags are true and then do what you want there.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but how do I check if all the boolean values are true without entering an infinite loop? I don't want to do this because then my application becomes non-responsive.

Comment: You don't need an infinite loop. Just check if all booleans are true on every `worker.RunWorkerCompleted`

Comment: YES! I understand now, hahah that makes me so happy.

Answer (score 1):

Using a *BackgroundWorker* is somewhat outdated since .Net 4.5 by task-returning async methods. This is nicely explained why [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html).

In your use case, you would probably end up with something as simple as:

```
public async Task DownloadTask()
{
   Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
   tasks[0] = DoSomeStuff();
   tasks[1] = DoSomeStuff();

   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Originally, I had used Tasks and not BackgroundWorkers but I have problems updating my UI with Tasks. With BackgroundWorkers it just works, but I'm not totally experienced with Tasks so I could be doing something wrong.

Comment: You cannot update UI elements when not in the UI thread. This is true for Tasks, but also for BackgroundWorkers. Tasks handles way better the context switch between threads, making it almost transparent in the code, when done right. For example, in my example, if DownloadTask is called from the UI thread, after the await instruction, you're back in the UI thread and can update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple workaround - use a counter that keeps track of all your backgroundworkers.

```
   int counter = 0;
```

In the DoWork of each backgroundworker:

```
    private void bwDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        //do other stuff
    }
```

and in each RunWorkerCompleted, decrement the counter and check if zero, which tells you that all backgroundworkers are done

```
    private void bwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            //All backgroundworkers are done, so do something
        }
    }
```